# Delete all rows by PartitionKey in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Is there any way how to delete all rows by a certain Partition Key using NodeJS?
My rows is composed by Partition Key + Sort Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no. The DynamoDB deleteItem API requires full partition + sort key. So what you would need to do is query by the partition key to get all items in the partition, then delete each individually. If you wanted to make it a little faster you could use batchWriteItem to combine some of the delete requests.